# Scrapy CrawlSpider parse_item for a 302 redirect response

Tags: redirect, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using a Scrapy `CrawlSpider` to crawl websites and process on their page content. For this I am using the [Scrapy Docs Crawlspider Example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example).

A particular page on the links takes in a parameter `target` via GET request (say `http://www.example.com?target=x`) and redirects (302) if the value is erroneous. On receiving this 302 HTTP response, scrapy follows the redirect, but doesn't processes the `response` in `parse_item` method, as intended by me.

I came across a few solutions suggesting `meta/dont_redirect/http_status_list` but none seem to be taking effect.

Please suggest how can I parse the response of 302 redirection, without/before following on the 302 redirected location.

Scrapy version: 0.24.6

Comment: First you should use scrapy v1+ and having `meta={'dont_redirect': True}` should stop the `RedirectMiddleware` which is enabled by default redirecting the redirect on redirect status codes like 302. If that doesn't help we need more info.

Comment: @Granitosaurus I know version 0.24 is quite old but I am working on an old base which cant be immediately migrated to v1.0 so will have to do with that only, moreover where exactly should this `meta={'dont_redirect': True}` be put ? Just defining it in the class definition does not helps it.

Comment: oh no, I've posted a detailed answer how to enable this :)

Answer (score 2):

To disable redirects you should add `meta={'dont_redirect': True)` to your yielded `scrapy.Request`s.
so your spider should look something like this:

```
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['http://example.com',]
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect':True})
```

What happens here is that scrapy has a default downloader middleware called [RedirectMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=dont_redirect#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect) which is enabled by default and handles all redirections, by supplying this meta argument you are telling this middleware to not do it's job for this particular request.

if you want to disable redirects for every request(which usually is not the best idea) you can just add

```
REDIRECTS_ENABLED = False
```

to your `settings.py` in scrapy project.

There is a brilliant illustration on scrapy docs on how all of the scrapy pieces, like middlewares and spiders, work together:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html

Comment: I guess I could not convey my target here correctly. I basically want to log all the links that I come across while scraping a website, so even if its a 302 response I would want the scrapy crawler to log the original link (which gives 302 response) as well as the target location specified in the response header and process both of them in `parse_item`.

Comment: Scrapy should indeed log everything. 302 links would come out as `scraping <website2> redirected from <website1>[302]` or something like that.

Comment: I decided to upgrade Scrapy to v1.0.5, that seems to be working better. Thanks for your help and advice :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class LagouSpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
    meta = {'dont_redirect': True, "handle_httpstatus_list": [302]}
    name = 'lagou'
    allowed_domains = ['www.lagou.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.lagou.com']
    login_url = "https://passport.lagou.com/login/login.html"
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False}
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("zhaopin/.*",)), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("gongsi/j\d+.html",)), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'jobs/\d+.html'), callback='parse_job', follow=True),
    )
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Host': 'www.lagou.com',
        'Referer': 'https://www.lagou.com/',
        'X-Anit-Forge-Code': '0',
        'X-Anit-Forge-Token': 'None',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        global rc, im
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/wqh/下载/chromedriver")
        browser.get(self.login_url)
        # ··········(some code)

       return [scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], cookies=cookie_dict, 
        meta=self.meta)]
    def parse_job(self, response):
        if response.status == 302:
            print("302")
            time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Some explanation along with this script would be helpful